# Is that possible to integrate a air app in native Android app

Tags: android, air

Adobe Flash Builder can build a air project to apk file.

But how to launch a air app from my native app?

Can I make a communication between two apps?

I want put the AIR project in my native app and build to **one single apk file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication between different applications/activities can be achieved via Intents and Intent Filters: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Sorry,I mean communicate with  air app not two native android app.